# How to handle "-> empty" in Kotlins "when"

Tags: kotlin

Lets assume the following when-statement:

```
when(a)
{
   x    -> doNothing()
   y    -> doSomething()
   else -> doSomethingElse()
}
```

Now i'm looking to eliminate the boilerplate-function "doNothing()", e.g.:

```
x ->        //doesn't compile
x -> null   //Android Studio warning: Expression is unused
x -> {}     //does work, but my corporate codestyle places each '{‘ in a new line, looking terrible
            //also, what is this actually doing?
```

Any better ideas?
I can't just eliminate `x ->` completely, as that would lead to `else -> doSthElse()`

Edit: directly after writing this Question, i figured out a possible answer `x -> Unit`. Any shortcomings with that?

Comment: `x -> Unit` is the nicest I've seen.

Comment: I like `else -> {}`

Comment: If when is not used as an expression you can also use an empty string "", or anything that returns a Unit. 
You can make a fun doNothing() that returns always a Unit, if you want the code to be more readable.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Kotlin has two existing possibilities to express a "do nothing" construct in when statements. Either Unit or an empty pair of braces. An empty block will just execute nothing. 
There's nothing else planned in that regard (see [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/explicit-do-nothing-construct/1972)).

To answer your question regarding "also, what is this actually doing?" for the empty block, looking at the bytecode and translating it into Java helps:

```
val x = 33
when(x)
{
    1 -> {}
    2 -> Int
    3 -> Unit
    else -> Double
}
```

Translates to

```
int x = 33;
switch(x) {
  case 1:
  case 3:
     break;
  case 2:
     IntCompanionObject var10000 = IntCompanionObject.INSTANCE;
     break;
  default:
     DoubleCompanionObject var1 = DoubleCompanionObject.INSTANCE;
}
```

Comment: Good to know {} and Unit don't create any strange artifacts :)